# How can I adapt my problem so that it is amenable to the simplex algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

According to the Wikipedia article, the Simplex algorithm depends on constraining all the unknowns to be >= 0.  I have a problem where one of my variables is highly likely to be negative in many cases.  How can I adapt the problem so I can use Simplex?

**EDIT**: example: say I have x, y and z and I want to find values (both >= 0) for x and y which minimize z, where I also have the constraints:

```
1.4x -y +z >= 0
-x +2.2y +z >= 0
```

Comment: Multiply your variable by $-1$. Make it positive. Maybe you should give us the whole problem, because that may not be the best, or even proper, way to deal with the issue.

Comment: But what if it's positive to begin with?

Comment: Can you give the whole problem, please? It's hard to say anything definite otherwise.

Comment: I don't see the problem. I mean, if you think there might be a negative solution, switch the sign of one variable everywhere in the problem. Solve it (maximize for z of course) and switch back.

Answer (score 1):

The standard trick is to replace $z$ with $z^+ - z^-$ throughout.

Comment: ...with $z^+$ and $z^-$ both taken to be nonnegative.